# Java Package Name Validation

Tags: java, android

In Java Documentation I found that naming convention of a package should be like this:

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces.

But I have seen lots of Classes in Java and Android like below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
```

What is the standard here? Are these examples are a deviation from the conventions?

Comment: what is the problem with that statements? You already wrote it "**Package** names are written in all lower case tp avoid conflict with the names of **classes** or **interfaces**" and "I have seen lots of **Classes**..."

Comment: in `import java.util.HashMap;` `java.util.` is a package name, and `HashMap` is a class name, exactly as documentation says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because

`import java.util.HashMap;`

`Hashmap` refers to the class, not the package.

It reads that :

`Hashmap` is a class found within the package of `java.util`

---

Here's the actual package and class in question:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Import statements consist of *two* parts, the package name and the actual class which resides in the package.  For example, your `import`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Actually says to import the `HashMap` class which resides in the `java.util` package.  In fact, the package name does consist only of lowercase letters.  But, the class is in upper camelcase, as is also the convention.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing

```
import some.package.with.WhatEverClass
```

with

```
import some.package.with.*
```

In other words: the upper case comes in because the last part of the import statement refers to a **class**, not a package.

This is similar to what you can do in python:

```
import re
```

will import the **whole** module, whereas that first java example is more like

```
from foo import bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right package name in java are written in lowercase. However, 
examples given in question are of import not package. 
Package in `HashMap` class would be like this package `java.util;`

And `java.util.HashMap` is fully qualified class name. Fully qualified class name(class name with package) are used in import.